# Unique witness form for $\Sigma^1_{n+1}$ formulas

Tags: logic, descriptive-set-theory

I am interested in equivalently transforming $\Sigma^1_{n+1}$ formulas $\exists Y\;\psi(X,Y)$ (with $\psi$ being $\Pi^1_n$) in the form $\exists Y\;\psi'(X,Y)$, where $\psi'$ is $\Pi^1_n$ and $\psi'(X,Y)\land \psi'(X,Y')\to Y=Y'$.

If we have (effective enough) lightface $\Pi^1_n$ uniformatization then there is a straightforward way to put each $\Sigma^1_{n+1}$ formula in this unique witness form (for a given formula $\exists Y\;\psi(X,Y)$ we take the uniformization of $\psi(X,Y)$ as $\psi'(X,Y)$). But of course generally $\psi'(X,Y)$  is not necessary a uniformization of $\psi(X,Y)$.

My question is whether there is essentially different way of putting $\Sigma^1_{n+1}$ formulas in unique witness form? And whether there are interesting examples of theories where for some $n$ it is possible to equivalently transform $\Sigma^1_{n+1}$ formulas in unique witness form but not possible to prove uniformization? More specifically is it possible to put $\Sigma^1_3$ formulas in unique witness form over $\mathsf{ZFC}$?

Comment: Is your first sentence trying to convey:  given $A(X, Y)$, find $B(X, Y)$ such that $\exists Y . A(X, Y) \iff \exists! Y.B(X, Y)$ ?

Comment: I was talking about slightly stronger property: given $A(X,Y)$, find $B(X,Y)$ such that 1. $\exists Y. A(X,Y)\iff \exists Y. B(X,Y)$ and 2. $\exists Y. B(X,Y)\Rightarrow\exists ! Y. B(X,Y)$.

Comment: Yes that is a stronger property.  If my algebra is right, it is what I wrote, conjunction with the requirement that when $A_x$ is not universally false, $B_x$ is inhabited no more than once.

Comment: Hope it isn't taboo for me to say this, but a question this detailed may get better attention at mathoverflow.net